# Objective-C - How to send a multiple parts message?

Tags: objective-c, message

Here's more explanation.

```
- (NSArray *)shipsAtPoint:(CGPoint)bomblocation withDamage:(BOOL)damaged;
```

How to send that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to read *The Objective-C Programming Language*, which you'll find in the Xcode docs.

```
[objectIWantToSendTheMessageTo shipsAtPont:somePoint withDamage:YES];
```

Comment: I'm already studying Stanford university course. Those docs are pretty complicated so I preferred Google, couldn't find it, so I came here.

And thanks for the answer. That solved it for me :)